# Analysis of infection data between two years using parametric or nonparametric tests?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, count-data

I have three years of infection data from 6 different hospitals.

```
      2010     2011    2012
1      1.3       2.5    1.03
2     3.35       2.5    2.6
3     4.1        1.8    2.5
4     2.0        3.65    .7
5     3.4        3.75    2.4
6     1.2        3.4     1.3
```

These numbers are rates (infections/10,000ptd). I need to determine significance between years. What I plan to do is run either an unpaired t-test for 2010/2011 and 2011/2012 or a Mann-Whitney U test. Since I only have three years of data, I feel that to compare all the data with ANOVA there wouldn't be high enough power to find significance. Does this sound reasonable or are there alternate testing I can do to find out if there is statistical significance between the years?

Comment: Why do you say *un*-paired? The hospitals surely act as blocks, don't they? Also, by doing separate tests to 'improve power' what you're actually doing is improving power by ramping up your overall type I error rate. If you are *actually prepared to do that*, make the type I error rate higher in the ANOVA and use that instead. These sound like scaled counts; if so, the t-test assumptions may be dodgy (why not analyze the counts with their exposures via something like a Poisson or quasi-Poisson regression model)?

Comment: Do you think that if I do perform a T-test that it should be paired? I originally thought this, but after asking a collegue she didn't think it should be paired because it's not the same group of people being exposed.I also understand the count side if I was using the number of infections. I would prefer to use the rates since each hospital is a different size and the number of PTD varies dramatically and using the rate will account for this. If I put it in SAS as: proc ttest data=x; class year; var rate; run; will that be sufficient?

Comment: While it's mostly not the same group of people being exposed, many other things are common within one hospital and not between them - things from the doctors and other staff, to the facilities at the hospital to the demographic mix of the population the hospital tends to draw from (age, race, gender, etc). You account for the different exposure in a (quasi-)Poisson GLM by putting the exposure (what you're dividing by) in as an offset, accounting for the different sizes of hospital. I am not the person to ask about SAS - I haven't used it in more than 20 years.